# JMeter If condition for 2 HTTP request's within a single thread

Tags: if-statement, jmeter

Access token is retrieved using HTTP request and it can be retrieved from 2 different servers.

Here I want to apply the if else condition, based on the success result from any of the request(which fetch the access token), i would need to execute further more HTTP requests.

Example: There are 2 servers like A and B.

If I get the access token from server A then I don't want to fetch the token from server B (tokens are retrieved using HTTP request).

Only upon successful retrieving of token from any server, I would require to proceed further (multiple HTTP requests will be triggered to accomplish the desired work).

Like, after retrieving access token from any server, I would post and get some data from DB using HTTP requests.[JMeter_Scenario_Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQcTj.png)

Comment: can you not use your HTTP request callback's for this purpose?

Comment: I am a Newbie to JMeter tool, so could you please iterate a bit more about HTTP request call back.

Comment: I dont know about jMeter.. perhaps this link may help https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-ajaxxhr-enabled-sites-jmeter

Comment: @ techie_28, I went through the URL, but no luck. :( Have updated the question with a snapshot of the scenario, upon which i am working on.

Comment: This was achieved very easily.

Comment: Steps:
1) Run the 1st HTTP request
2) Add an Logic Controller --> If Controller. And,
3) Define the condition in "IF Controller" is “${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}”

This would solve the scenario.